# Not able to save data correctly with extended user model

Tags: django, django-models

Extended auth User to Profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  age = models.IntegerField(default=18)
  university = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
  department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
```

Views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
      try:
        with transaction.atomic():
          form.save()
          profile_form.save()
      except DatabaseError:
        pass    

      username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
      messages.success(request, f'Account Created for {username}!')
      return redirect('jmiforums:homepage')
  else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
  return render(request, 'jmiforums/register.html', {"form":form, "profile_form": profile_form,})`
```

Register form

```
<form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">JMI Forum</legend>
          {{ form.as_p }}
          {{ profile_form.as_p }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Data is saved twice every time in Profile table, one with User connected but no other data from profile model, and other vice versa.

Comment: post your `UserRegisterForm` and `ProfileForm`

Comment: what OP answered worked for me. But if you want i can post is for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably not allow for `Profile` without `user` (remove `null=True`). Assuming your `UserRegisterForm` just saves the `User` model and your `ProfileForm` is just for the `Profile` model:

```
if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()
    profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
    profile.user = user
    profile.save()
```

You use `commit=False` to create the instance without saving it, then you add the relationship to the `user`, and then you save the profile. Also make sure you don't create an empty `Profile` when creating a `User` (e.g. if you hooked a `post_save` handler on `User`, as described in the Django docs).